# Convert vertical DataTable to C# model

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a values in Datatable verticallly like this

[image]

I need to convert this into list of object like this

```
var listOfEmployees = new List<Employee>();

listOfEmployees.Add(new Employee{
    Id=221, Salary=10000, Age=31
});
listOfEmployees.Add(new Employee{
    Id=222, Age=31
});
```

What I have done

```
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i < dTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dTable.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
       var value = dTable.Rows[j][i];
       // for Primary Key Check if exist in list
       // Match Column Name
       // Fill Value
    }
}
```

But I am not able to think of logic to fit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model:

```
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

Data:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Primary Key", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Column Name", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

dataTable.Rows.Add(221, "Salary", "10000");
dataTable.Rows.Add(221, "Department", "Support");
dataTable.Rows.Add(221, "Age", "31");
dataTable.Rows.Add(222, "Salary", "1000");
dataTable.Rows.Add(222, "Age", "22");
```

LINQ code:

```
var employees = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(
        row => row.Field<int>("Primary Key"),
        row => new { ColumnName = row.Field<string>("Column Name"), Value = row["Value"] }
    )
    .Select(g => new Employee
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnName == "Salary")?.Value),
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnName == "Age")?.Value),
        Department = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnName == "Department")?.Value.ToString()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do with this List object or can do it by anonymously.

```
var listOfEmployees = new List<Employee>();
listOfEmployees = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                   select new Employee()
                   {
                      Id = dr["PrimaryKey"],
                      Salary = dr["Salary"].ToString(),
                      Age = dr["Age"].ToString(),
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: In Column Name we need to find Column and its actual Value will be in Value

Comment: I believe this answers your question compeletly

Comment: in column name we will get different properties ie salary department age

Comment: @VishalPandey Ahh, updated the answer, Its simple way to achieve this. The things were a bit mixed up with other syntax.

Comment: There are no `Salary` and `Age` column in the table. It's wrong answer.

Comment: Take the filled DataTable from my answer and try executing your code.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov its just sample code to give the logic that how to do it. Column can be used as per own requirement.